# How do I change iOS iTunes Store Region?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-store

I was looking at movies reviews online, and a hyper link took me to iTunes, it said "Hey this isn't available in the US but it is in the UK, would you like to change stores?"  So I said sure, why not?  Now I'm stuck in the UK store.  I tried Settings -> iTunes & App Stores -> Apple ID -> View Apple ID -> Country/Region, but it doesn't work because of active subscriptions and passes (which I do have under the US store).  How do I get back the US store front for my iTunes Store on my iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quit the iTunes Store and the App Store on your iPhone. Then go to 'Settings > iTunes > iTunes & App Store' and sign out of your Apple ID, and then back in. When you relaunch the iTunes Store app it should then automatically direct you to the iTunes Store for the appropriate country.